# Javascript data transformation with single iteration

Tags: javascript

I have data structure like this.

```js
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
]
```

I want to transofrm this into below structure.

```js
const transformedData = ['source1', 'source2', 'target1', 'target2'];
```

Below is how I solved it

```js
const transformedData = [...new Set([...this.data.map(d => d[0]), ...this.data.map(d => d[1])])];
```

Is there any way we can avoid the 2 iteration inside `Set()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract first 2 value from array and merge them and then get all the unique values.

```js
const data = [ ['source1', 'target1', 1], ['source2', 'target2', 2], ['source1', 'target2', 2]],
      result = [...new Set([...[0, 1].flatMap(i => data.map(arr => arr[i]))])];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Source and target, I gave generally. It can be any string. To get the order I think sort wont work.

Comment: So, you want value at index 0 to come first and followed by value at index 1. Right? 
See the updated solution.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in your example, you have more than just two iterations because you spread all items. From my point of view, the most efficient approach uses two interactions (O 2n)
First, you loop over the item in the array and add them to a set, next you have to convert the set back to an array

```js
// input
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
];

// store items in set to keep them unique
const result = new Set();

// iterate over items and add first and second entry to the set
data.forEach(item => {
  result.add(item[0]);
  result.add(item[1]);
});

// convert set to array
const arr = [...result]
```

You could use `Array.flatMap` to iterate over them in just one loop but you would end up with duplicates in you result:

```js
const res = data.flatMap(item => [item[0], item[1]])

// [ 'source1', 'target1', 'source2', 'target2', 'source1', 'target2' ]
```

Comment: what if implemented like this? you only convert to a set once.

```javascript
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
];

const result = []
data.forEach(item => {
  result.push(item[0]);
  result.push(item[1]);
});

const arr = [...new Set(result)]
```

Comment: It's the exact same just the other way around. Actually, it is a bit less efficient, because your resulting array, contains more items, which get reduced later to a set.

Comment: Thank you. what if we used `indexOf()` instead of `set` operator?

Comment: Same, `indexOf` is `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` the `data` and return element at 0th and 1st index position, in form an array. Then, you can use Array's `flat()` method, to convert multi-dim array to into single dimension. You can also use `new Set()` and spread (`...`) operator to remove the duplicates.

```js
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
]

let res = data.map(e=>[e[0], e[1]])

res = [...new Set(res.flat())]

console.log(res)
```

---

**Note**: If you strictly want array in ordered form (like `['source1', 'source2', 'target1', 'target2']`), you need to use two `forEach`s, one for 0th index element, and other for 1st index element, and add them to the `Set`.

```js
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
]

let set = new Set();

data.forEach(e=>{set.add(e[0]);})
data.forEach(e=>{set.add(e[1]);})

res = [...set]

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Source and target, I gave generally. It can be any string. To get the order I think sort wont work.

Comment: @SijilSasidharan Oh ok. I have updated the answer. Please check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Set are not ordered and you can just remove it.

```
const transformedData = data.map(a => a[0]).concat(data.map(a => a[1]))
//  or
const transformedData = [...data.map(a => a[0]), ...data.map(a => a[1])]
// or if order doesn't matter
const transformedData = data.map(a => a.slice(0, 2)).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

This way uses spread at the end but it uses one iteration over data array and keeps the order.

```js
const data = [
  ['source1', 'target1', 1],
  ['source2', 'target2', 2],
  ['source1', 'target2', 2]
];

const res = [...new Set(data.reduceRight((acc, arr, i, dat) => {
  acc.unshift(arr[0]); 
  acc.push(dat[dat.length - i - 1][1]); 
  return acc;
}, []))];

console.log(res);
```